# Navigation and Binding error in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I have a main page in C# which gets navigated to from a previous page.So, `OnNavigatedTo`.In this `OnNavigatedTo` I have initailized an array.

```
     public MainPage()  //default constructor
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
          this.RandomNumb01 = hello(1, 7);
         }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
             FillGraph obj = new FillGraph();   //another class which contains the values 
            graph = obj.enterValue();//My graph will be get values here
        }

   int[,] graph;

public string RandomNumb01_1 { get; set; } //This is for the binding of a button's content in XAML



   string hello(int i,int j)
        {

            string s = "";
            if (graph[i, j] == -1 || graph[i, j] == -10) //I get error here that the array is null
                return s;
            else
            return graph[i, j].ToString();

        }
```

So when I have the values of array updated in the `OnNavigatedTo` method,why does it show array is null.Also how can I fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You call `hello` from the constructor. At this point, `graph` hasn't been created yet. The `OnNavigatedTo` method won't be called until later (except for the fact that you have crashed).

Simply stepping through the code with a debugger and using the **Autos** window should highlight this problem.